# How to set up pipeline.config file with one class to train on mobilenet v3 large? and also how to set fine tune checkpoint?

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, mobilenet

I have to set class of one in pipeline.config,i changed the number of classes to 1 and i started training its showing an error

```
InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Restoring from checkpoint failed.
```

This is most likely due to a mismatch between the current graph and the graph from the checkpoint.

Please ensure that you have not altered the graph expected based on the checkpoint. Original error:

```
Assign requires shapes of both tensors to match. lhs shape= [1,1,256,12] rhs shape= [1,1,256,546]
[[node save/Assign_86 (defined at /home/drive/Downloads/models- 
master/research/object_detection/legacy/trainer.py:378) @bmabey @alextp 
@moonboots @ewilderj @jtoy @tensorflowbutler
```

And also how to set fine tune checkpoint ?

Comment: what is your research and what you tried till now?

Comment: looks like you're using the legacy train.py. Try instead training using model_main.py.